# Awk replace column by part of string from another column

Tags: awk

`Input.txt` file :

```
A    B       C
-9  -9  01:662414
-9  -9  01:662622
01  731718  01:731718
```

Desired `output.txt` file:

```
A    B       C
01  662414  01:662414
01  662622  01:662622
01  731718  01:731718
```

I am looking for a way how to replace columns `$1` and `$2` with parts from column `$3`, as shown above.

I tried `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { OFS=FS=":" } 
  NR==FNR { split ($3,one,":"); two[$1] = one[1]; next } 
  $1 in two { $1 = two[$1]; print }' input.txt >> output.txt
```

but it didnt work. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short **`awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR > 1{ split($3, a, ":"); $1=a[1]; $2=a[2] }1' file
```

- `NR > 1` - perform action for lines starting from the 2nd line
- `split($3, a, ":")` - split the 3rd field value `$3` into array `a` by separator `:`

---

The output:

```
A    B       C
01 662414 01:662414
01 662622 01:662622
01 731718 01:731718
```

Comment: Thank you for help!